# Separating AJAX response into multiple Divs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I asked this question earlier but did not quite word it right. I am using a live search example with the following code:

```
<script>
    function showResult(str) {
        if (str.length==0) { 
            document.getElementById("livesearch").innerHTML="";
            document.getElementById("livesearch").style.border="0px";
            return;
        }
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {  // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
                document.getElementById("livesearch").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                document.getElementById("livesearch").style.border="1px solid #A5ACB2";
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","livesearch.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
</script>
```

This sets the contents of the livesearch Div to a list of items echoed by the php script livesearch.php. This is pretty close to my goal, but I actually want each echoed item to be in their own expandable div such as this [JQuery example](http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/jquerymobile_collapsibles.asp).

My return string looks like this:

```
Title 1
Info 1 about title 1
Info 2 about title 1
Title 2
Info 1 about title 2
Info 2 about title 2
```

Here is the livesearch.php:

```
<?php    
    $xmlDoc=new DOMDocument();
    $xmlDoc->load("spells.xml");

    $x=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('title');
    $y=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('type');
    $z=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('casting');
    $a=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('range');
    $b=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('description');

    $q=$_GET["q"];

    $hint="";
    $results = array();

    for($i=0; $i<($x->length); $i++) 
    {
        if(stristr($x->item($i)->nodeValue,$q))
        {
            array_push( $results, $i );
        }
    }

    foreach( $results as $result )
    {
        echo '  <div>';
        echo '      <h1>'.$x->item($result)->nodeValue.'</h1>';
        echo '      <p>Type: '.$y->item($result)->nodeValue.'<br>';
        echo '      Time: '.$z->item($result)->nodeValue.'<br>';
        echo '      Range: '.$a->item($result)->nodeValue.'<br>';
        echo '      Description: '.$b->item($result)->nodeValue.'</p>';
        echo '  </div>';
    }
?>
```

Currently they are all echoed back as a single string. I'm not quite sure how I can separate each line of the string into its own Div.

Does anyone know how to do this? Any hint in the right direction would be really appreciated.

Comment: Since you do not show your return data it would be hard to know. Possibly `.split()`.

Comment: Can you post the code of livesearch.php please. I can only assume you query a database and thus return the results. Am I right? Don't forget to take out your database connection string and infos

Comment: @IndieRok You can find the code of the PHP here: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_livesearch.asp

Comment: I am actually searching through an XML file. I will post the script. I also edited my post to show the return string format.

Comment: @KriptSkitty Could you post and actual response instead of that structure?

Comment: I modified the livesearch.php so it is no longer the same.

Comment: @robot9706 The response is echoed in the foreach loop. What I want to do is get an expandable div working  instead of having to echo basic html back. I'm not a very strong web developer...

Comment: @IndieRock I guess I'm kind of doing that right now, but when I try to change the Div I'm sending into that JQuery expandable Div, it doesn't seem to want to become an expandable. Any idea why?

Comment: You might consider just returning a JSON-encoded data structure back to calling javascript rather than HTML.  For example, this might be a json-encoded array of objects.  This would make it much easier to work with in javascript. You would then be moving the HTML "template" into the javascript as well.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I didn't see the update

Comment: @MikeBrant Wow yeah that would be a way easier approach. I'll give that a shot! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Mike Brant's answer in the comments is to instead return json that can be modified with Javascript. This is a much easier solution. Thanks!

Comment: @MikeBrant if there's anyway to mark you as the answerer let me know!

Comment: You are allowed to answer your own questions on javascript.  I don't have time to code up solution at the moment.  You might consider adding your solution, when you get to it and marking it as the answer to your own question for future readers to benefit from.